# Visual Studio 2017: Azure functions unit test and local.settings.json issue

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-functions

I'm developing a Azure Functions backend application on Visual Studio 2017 Community. That's almost OK, but now I'm trying to write unit tests and - in general - it works fine, but not everything because it doesn't take the values from local.settings.json file.

I have a class with the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Includes
{
    public static class VariablesGlobales
    {
        public static int MaximoLicenciasAsignar
        {
            get { return Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAXIMO_LICENCIAS_ASIGNAR"))); }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine when the execution of the function is doing trough Visual Studio or CLI, but, when I execute the unit test, the attribute VariablesGlobales.MaximoLicenciasAsignar is always zero, no matter what I try.

The local.settings.json file is being copy on the bin folder, properly updated.

Actually, I don't know how to fix it, cause this problema doesn't let me make the full test, and my goal is to configurate CI and CD in VSTS, but without a full implementation of unit test, I can't.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated. Thank's a lot in advance.

Regards,

Rodrigo

Comment: Can't you just define variables for the build definition in VSTS? I don't think local.settings.json will be used in a CI environment because it's not local (based on my understanding).

Comment: Hi Dan, thank's for reply but, I'm not sure if I'm completely understanding what are you saying. Could you please be more specific? Thank's a lot

Comment: How are testing the app in VSTS? You should be able to set environment variables for the build when editing the build definition.

Comment: Hi again, finally I set up the values in the "Variables" section in VSTS build as you said, and everything is running well! so, thank's a lot for your help. Regards